# Get specific child of parent list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following code:

```
sortableList = $("#itemlist");
$(sortableList).click(function(){
   console.log($(this).children().attr('id'));
});
```

The list contains elements that are direct descendants with ids from id_0 to id_9. I want to get the specific id of the element I am clicking. By running above the above code, the function logs only the id of the first child, regardless of the child I click on.

Comment: Which one is specific id? first, second, ..?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `#itemlist` has `div` as its children:

```
$("#itemlist").on("click", "div", function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the children are divs, but it worked once I replaced li with div. Thank you!